# CSS3 Spin Animation: spin back when unhovering

Tags: css, css-animations

I have this code that spins an image when hovering:

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .15s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: .15s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: .15s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: .15s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79FHN/1/

I want it to spin to the other direction when un-hovering. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Please read about the difference between *animations* and *transitions*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can refactor your code to great extent, all you need is

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/79FHN/13/)

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    transition: 1s linear;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

The issue with your code was, that you were using `@keyframes` which are nothing but animation, so once it triggers, you need to write a separate keyframe for reversing. As your animation was not so complex, I preferred using simple CSS3 properties to get the job done.

If you feel the animation nudges your icon or you deliberately want to nudge on hover, you can use `transform-origin` property.

---

Thanks to [@Second Rikudo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17808569#17808569) for pointing out the `linear` issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) 

What part am I doing wrong ? 
http://jsfiddle.net/79FHN/1/

Comment: tried this too: 
`img {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
 transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: 1s;

}`

Comment: @Hatul Did you read my answer? get rid of all your code, and just use what I provided, you won't need anything else

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't look like it spins the same way. 
it kinda spins from the bottom of the image and not from the center, or am I wrong? :X

Comment: @Hatul looks same to me, if you want to tweak the origin, use `transform-origin` property as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: @Hatul please see the updated code, I feel whats missing was `linear` animation

Comment: hmm.. I tried to use:
`transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;`
but still spins the same way and not from the middle. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes, you added the "linear" at the end but it looks the same and spins the same.

Comment: Looks really good, but on the image I am working on it doesn't look the same. I guess because of size difference. 
So I uploaded the image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2ns3yao.png

Comment: I changed 65px of what you sent me to 10 (that is +- half of the size of the image) and it looks good now. 

Thank you very very much!!! Helped me a lot!